# If match on line 1 grab content on line 2

Tags: php, regex, variables, preg-match

The code below picks every line that contains of the word "Homepage:" and extract what's after the semicolon. However what I want instead is that if match on the word "Homepage:" what's on the next line should be grabbed and put in a variable.

How could that be done?

```
if (preg_match( '/Homepage:/', $text, $match )) {
    $pieces = explode(':', $text);
    $urls[] = trim($pieces[1]);
}
```

**Example:**

```
Homepage:    <--- if match
http://www.fooland.com    <--- grab this and put in variable
```

Comment: Will there be more then 1 line below `Homepage:`, if yes do you want to grabbled only one or all.

Comment: @Ravi: The question is clear: "what's on the *next* line should be grabbed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/Homepage:.*\n(.*)/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
Homepage: # Match Homepage:
.*        # Match any characters except linebreaks
\n        # Match a linebreak
(.*)      # Match and capture the contents of the entire line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **explode()** in php

```
$urlResult = explode(':', $url)
echo $urlResult[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with regular expression `'/Homepage:\n/'`